# Generic typescript function that works for extended interfaces

Tags: typescript

I would like to create a function that works for any interface extending from a top level interface that can take an unpersisted interface (no `id` property) and return a persisted one (has `id` property).

The 2 top level types I want to use are:

```ts
interface UnpersistedAnimal {
    name: string; // Should be set before persist to make the object valid
}

interface PersistedAnimal extends UnpersistedAnimal {
    id: number; // Only here after database persist
}
```

I then tried to create a conditional type that other interfaces could inherit from:

```ts
type AbstractAnimal<persisted=true> = persisted extends true ?
    PersistedAnimal :
    UnpersistedAnimal;
```

Then other interfaces should be able to inherit those 2 interfaces and the type system should distinguish between persisted and unpersisted entities. For example:

```ts
interface Duck extends AbstractAnimal<false> {
    name: "Duck";
}
```

This is the full example of the closest thing I got working:

```ts
interface UnpersistedAnimal {
    name: string;
}

interface PersistedAnimal extends UnpersistedAnimal {
    id: number;
}

type AbstractAnimal<persisted=true> = persisted extends true ?
    PersistedAnimal :
    UnpersistedAnimal;

interface Duck extends AbstractAnimal<false> {
    name: "Duck";
}
interface Goose extends AbstractAnimal<false> {
    name: "Goose";
}

// This function should take a persisted or unpersisted animal,
// but always return a persisted animal.
function persistAnimal<T extends AbstractAnimal<false>>(animal: T): T & {id: number} {
    const persistedAnimal = animal as AbstractAnimal<true>;
    persistedAnimal.id = 1;
    return animal;
}

const unpersistedDuck = {name: "Duck"} as Duck;
console.log(unpersistedDuck.id); // Should show a warning
const persistedDuck = persistAnimal(unpersistedDuck);
console.log(persistedDuck.id); // Should work and be type "Duck"

const unpersistedGoose = {name: "Goose"} as Goose;
console.log(unpersistedGoose.id); // Should show a typescript warning
const persistedGoose = persistAnimal(unpersistedGoose);
console.log(persistedGoose.id); // Should work and be type "Goose"
```

I would like if the function would work by taking a type `Duck<persisted=false>` and would return `Duck<persisted=true>`. The same should also work for Goose or any other types that inherit from AbstractAnimal.

## Typescript playground

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKogA7QM7G5AEwEERgBbOAG2QG8BYAKGWeRDjIgC5l8pQBzANyMAvo0ahIsRCgAKOPIRLkqyCAA9IIAtjSYF%20CMVIVq9Ji2AFuIAK5kARtGEMxDRmACeWZEQe9EMGVTAB4sKFxDAmQAXmQwKFsIAD5Y5HDIwjVNCG1dBKTkAH5GFmR5CMUjYNVOUpZ0DKrjFUoXCXBoeCRkABFbBABrbK0dX38EwJrKEPhKbBTaeuY2Dm4AIn6h9Zc3DqlulABxAHsThZHcsb8AhCCTKlmqBdTzMtWuZHXT84gd0XEDAA9EDkAAVAAWeGQMFsIDuwBOIB4EJOtko0TAcEGKDg6QMWROUGQcKaUWQcAelAANIwQcgHLYwBTKAB3OCeXRQCBgWxQZF4slZSmtAB0jFh8LAiORQumITBlzy41u91aT3mKWSAAoRaZuGCAJQG5AAMloyCsNnsTmJIiWFmYCCR%20HxlSi0zSetUcF0N0md3lBRSLjKQuqVNFVjSAEZQyxubz%20RSqbtAc6QK7SQSjFthnEaKx2J9NgNButkPbfX0yy4M9gTpQIKLKCd%20Nrs%207CHmowRDYJkPSAMqo9HRbCo1kU5Ds-kCRj15nhgh5tJyqkd-Rd3Nl-sLl2N5ut9vLntWfuD0EjtEYmdE4aU6JOeLeFCl7bpl3MzuZIw-C4FkWaxfP%20fyVhSuigXWB5Ni2babsuoG9hew6jreE4nFOeJeFg2AIHwGDMrOpAgPw%206ZkuOYEKBa4EtMCFUaBe4MPWh5wSejFnAsyEDqhN7RKy94pk%20KA4W%20oHrIwQA)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. First, your `AbstractAnimal` isn't an interface, so you can't extend from it.  But typeScript's type system is structural, not nominal, so as long as the function returns a type which is structurally equivalent to your desired `Duck<true>`, I don't see what the problem is.  If there is an actual problem you're facing, could you please provide a [mre] that clearly shows the issue?  Ideally an error that jumps out at you, or a callout to the place where the problem is happening.

Comment: (continued) Alternatively, please look at [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mLXDam) and tell me if that meets your needs, and if not, what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `T` to extend `boolean` instead, like so:

```
function persistAnimal<T extends boolean>(animal: AbstractAnimal<T>): PersistedAnimal {
    const persistedAnimal = animal as AbstractAnimal<true>;
    persistedAnimal.id = 1;
    return persistedAnimal;
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=23&ssc=1&pln=28&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKogA7QM7G5AEwEERgBbOAG2QG8BYAKGWeRDjIgC5l8pQBzANyMAvo0ahIsRCgAKOPIRLkqyCAA9IIAtjSYF%20CMVIVq9Ji2AFuIAK5kARtGEMxDRmACeWZEQe9EMGVTAB4sKFxDAmQAXmQwKFsIAD5Y5HDIwjVNCG1dBKTkAH5GFmR5CMUjYNVOUpZ0DKrjFUoXCXBoeCRkABFbBABrbK0dX38EwJrKEPhKbBTaeuY2Dm4AIn6h9Zc3DqlulABxAHsThZHcsb8AhCCTKlmqBdTzMtWuZHXT84gd0XEDAA9EDkAAVAAWeGQMFsIDuwBOIB4EJOtko0TAcEGKDg6QMWROUGQcKaUWQcAelAANIwQcgHLYwBTKAB3OCeXRQCBgWxQZF4slZSmtAB0jFh8LAiORQumITBlzyDLOlAglOSAAoRaZuDdJnd5WDkgBKbgVTLVKlLCzMBBI-D4ypRaZpHWqOC6fVQKZUkIFFIuMpCq1iqxpACMQZY3N5-Kdlpapl2gPtIEdpIJRi2wziNFY7E%20mwGg3WyBEFN0OZcaewJzVosoJ34mszzsIOdFVhNgmQ9IAyqj0dFsKjWRTkOz%20QJGLXmSGCDm0nKqa39O3syWe7OHfWII3m5qF53u72B0OMZOicNKdEnPFvChi9tUw7mW3Ez8LnmC2svl%20-nLStkAAmtdwbJsWw-ZoAK7Agez7UFBzRS9RxOcc8S8LBsAQPgMGZKdSBAfgd3TecswIADlwJaY1wXADtwYWs9wPFt6LOBY4IQ88UOiVlrwpbQGRQLCnwA9ZGCAA)